# ¿Cómo configurar “django-baton 2.2.1”?

Tags: django-3.2.4

Estoy trabajando con Django 3.2.4 y django-baton 2.2.1, pero tengo algunos problemas con la configuración. El primer problema es que no me muestra las vistas previas de las imágenes, a pesar de poner en la configuración: `BATON = {'ENABLE_IMAGES_PREVIEW': True,}`. Por otra parte, tengo un “User” personalizado, que incluye un `ImageField` para el avatar, pero “baton” me pide en su configuración el `GRAVATAR_DEFAULT_IMG`, pero no sé cómo indicarle que el valor de ese campo es el avatar que deseo mostrar en la aplicación. Por último, como mi clase “User’ se encuentra en otra aplicación, en las “app_list” el link de acceso se muestra en la lista correspondiente a dicha aplicación, ¿existe alguna forma de que se muestre en la lista “Autenticación y autorización”?